# probability .. having a round table of ten people what is the probability of choosing 3 consecutive seats?

Tags: probability

actually i have two questions about this .. in the Art of solving problems introduction to probability and counting . the solution is as follow 
all the possible combinations of 3 seats out of 10 is 10 chose 3 .. and the number of successes is 10 ??

why is it just 10 ? shouldn't be this a round table so the last one and the first two are consecutive seats also the last two and the first one ? which makes it 12 not 10 ..

the second question is :- why isnt it possible to do this :-

1. -we have 1 probability of choosing anyone in the round table , which leaves us with 9.
2. then to pick a consecutive seat we have 2/9
3. then to pick another consecutive seat we have 2/8

shouldn't the total probability be 1*2/9*2/8 ?

Comment: Looking clockwise, each one of the $10$ could be the start of a block of three consecutive seats.  Every block must have a start, so this is all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only $10$ ways to have three consecutive seats.  Working clockwise, each block must have a starting seat and every seat can be the first seat in a consecutive block.

To your calculation:  you correctly compute the probability of getting three seats in a row where each successive seat (after the first) adjoins one of the previously selected seats.  However that is not what was asked.  You could also get three consecutive seats by, say, choosing $\#1$, then $\#3$, then $\#2$.

Comment: isnt by using combination "choose order doesn't matter" ? by using 10 choose 3 we get that 1,3,2 is exactly the same as 1,2,3 ? or i'm getting something wrong here ?

Comment: Your method incorrectly brings order back into it.  You would not, for example, count the example I gave of $1,3,2$ though it clearly should be counted (so your probability comes out too low).  Suppose there were $4$ seats in a circle.  Then the correct answer is $1$.  But you get $\frac 23 \times \frac 22<1$.

Comment: that's absolutely right ,  that was of a great help to me . **thanks**  ^^